# Organizing grid in a Django template

Tags: html, css, django

I'm looking at a table (grid) in a django template, it's almost like I want ... I want to leave the 'douglas' and 'douglas2' variables more right but I'm horrible with front-end (html / Css) I'm just having to break a branch, how can I make these two elements get more right? I have tried to set a class css for them and use the "margin-left" but it is loading all ...

**file.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
</!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link href="{% static 'css/app.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
{% for m in matrice %}
  <div class="fp">
  {% for n in m %}
        <p class="sp">{{n}}</p>
  {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**file.css**

```
body {
    background-color: #dbffdb
}

.div {
    background-color: #42f453;
}

.tr {
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: black;
}

.sp {

    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: red;
    padding:10px;
}
```

Comment: Where in your code the `'douglas'` and `'douglas2'` are shown? Could you be more specific of exactly what you want?

Comment: I want show a grid with columns and lines, where the column 0 receive names of candidates that was evaluated by the evaluators that are the names ('douglas' and 'douglas2' in this case) in the line 0, and the rest of the slots of the table receive the score corresponding of your candidate(column 0) and the evaluator( line 0)...a want put the line 0 more to the left, to the evaluators stay aligned of the notes, try rum my html if you can, you see that this line is a little misaligned...I hope I have been clear.Thanks for the attention